# CLion STL containers not displaying correctly in debugger on Fedora 23

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, gdb, clion

When I use the GDB of CLion for debugging on vectors for example, no value is printed at all, even if the vector is in fact filled. I have activated the GNU C++ view, which effectively hides the *M* inner variables, but it still doesn't show anything. I tried searching on google but I can't find any info about it, as it is written everywhere this is provided out of the box.

I am on Fedora 23, I am using g++ 5.3.1, I am on CLion 2016.2 with the bundled CMake and GDB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some push_back calls in the code you are debugging? This looks related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7166 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7032

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003437800/comments/360001571540

Answer (score 7):

Go here and UNCHECK this checkbox. It helped to me.

> Settings -> Build, Execution, Delpoyment -> Debugger -> Data Views ->
> C/C++ -> "Enable GNU C++ library renders" [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuRcN.png)

then restart debug session

Answer (score 1):

Here are my example codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    auto *v = new std::vector<int>();
    v->push_back(1);
    v->push_back(2);
    v->push_back(3);
    v->push_back(4);
    return 0;
}
```

set a breakpoint as usual, click on this thing.

[image: click on this thing]

then write `*v` in the Code Fragment, you can see values in vectors.

[image: you can see values in vectors]

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003437800/comments/360001571540